# Maintaining FIFO when using threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I am attempting to perform an expensive and variable length task on elements received in a sequential manner. It is imperative that element order is maintained while still processing each element quickly.

Below is a SSCWE (*W* for *wrong*!) and is my attempt at parallelizing the processing. Is there a way to ensure that each call to `processSomething()` executes in its own thread while still maintaining FIFO when I look at the `ExecutorCompletionService`?

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ThreadingHelper {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
    ExecutorCompletionService<String> compService 
        = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(pool);

    // process some data
    processSomething(compService, "1.");
    processSomething(compService, "2..");
    processSomething(compService, "3...");
    processSomething(compService, "4....");
    processSomething(compService, "5.....");

    // print out the processed data
    try {
        System.out.println(compService.take().get());
        System.out.println(compService.take().get());
        System.out.println(compService.take().get());
        System.out.println(compService.take().get());
        System.out.println(compService.take().get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static synchronized void processSomething(
        CompletionService<String> compService, final String x) {
    Callable<String> c = new Callable<String>() {

        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            // this represents the variable and expensive 
                            // amount of time it takes to process x
            long rand = (long) (Math.random() * 100);
            Thread.sleep(rand);

            // this represents the processing of x
            String xProcessed = x.replace(".", "!");

            return xProcessed;
        }
    };
    compService.submit(c);
}
}
```

Typical output is

```
4!!!!
2!!
1!
5!!!!!
3!!!
```

but I want

```
1!
2!!
3!!!
4!!!!
5!!!!!
```

Comment: The `processSomething` method is synchronized but your critical section is in `call`.

Comment: If you want the output to be in order then you need to make your pipeline more asynchronous. The completion service is designed exactly to process things out of order - to get things as they are done.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, do you mean more synchronous? It just seems like there should be a class out there that helps me go full throttle ahead but at the end make sure all the pieces are still in order.

Comment: You're submitting the tasks in order, but those are running out of order since there is no guarantee in which order threads will run.

Comment: Either you don't have anything that gathers things up - i.e. more asynchronous. Or you simply use `invokeAll` and wait for everything to complete - it will remain in the order you passed in the data.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, my thinking in synchronizing `processSomething()` is to assure that each callable is added to the `ExecutorCompletionService` in the correct order. The problem I face is that `ExecutorCompletionService` does not maintain order.

Comment: Asynchronous execution doesn't typically care about order. Using [nosid's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22923673/438154) you can at least print them in the right order even if they weren't executed sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *Futures* instead of the *CompletionService* to get the results in a particular order and still benefit from parallel execution:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
futures.add(pool.submit(makeCallable("1.")));
// ...
for (Future<String> future : futures) {
    try {
        System.out.println(future.get());
    } catch (...) {
        ...
    }
}

public static Callable<String> makeCallable(String x) {
    Callable<String> c = ...;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Thank you muchly! I've tested this using System.currentTimeMillis() as best as I can tell, it satisfies both requirements of order and parallelization.

Comment: If the incoming msg is continuous, does that mean the future list is a ring buffer?

Comment: @ying: You can use a `Queue` instead of a `List` in this situation. A _ring buffer_ is a special implementation of a `Queue` with a fixed maximum size.

Comment: @nosid a priority Q and a separate thread actually. In order to know what the next sequence item to output, should there be a UUID atomic assignment for each new task at the beginning and a separate thread to check priority Q (busy spinning or via notification)? Also need to wrap all exception and ping the threads in thread pool so the priority Q thread won't starve in case of poison msg and dead thread. It looks disruptor is much simpler to handle this continuous scenario.